# Using ExecuteTransactionRequest to create related entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I've got Entity types that are in a parent-child relationship.

Since `ExecuteTransactionRequest` executes multiple message requests in **one** tranasaction, would the following work as I intend it to?

There are 3 parents with no children to start with:

```
//Create a 4th parent
cs_parent parent4 = new cs_parent{ cs_name = "p4" };
CreateRequest createParentRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = parent4 };
request.Requests.Add(createParentRequest);

EntityCollection parents 
  = context.RetrieveMultiple(/*fetchExpression to get all parents (I'm expecting 4 now)*/);

//Create a child for each parent
foreach (var p in parents.Entities)
{
  cs_child child = new cs_child
  {
    cs_parentid = p.ToEntityReference();
  }
  CreateRequest createChildRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = child };
  request.Requests.Add(createChildRequest);
}
response = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)context.Execute(request);
```

Would I be getting 4 parents with one child each then, or only 3 since when I'm retrieving multiple, the 4th one hasn't been created yet (?)?

If not, how do I revise my code ideally with still **one** `Execute` command at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually run your code for myself to be 100% sure, but it looks like it's going to error out because the fourth parent record doesn't have the necessary info on it at the time you assign it as an `EntityReference` on the child entity.  You can work around this easily though.  CRM allows for this type of situation where inter-dependent records can all be submitted within one batch `Create` request.  Normally when you create a record in CRM, the system assigns it a unique identifier (guid), but you can override this simply by assigning the guid yourself, then you have what you need to set it as a `EntityReference` on other objects.  So when you create the fourth parent, you would have something like this:

```
cs_parent parent4 = new cs_parent { cs_name = "p4",cs_parentId = Guid.NewGuid());
```

Just guessing at the Id field on your entity, but you get the idea.

One thing I'm not sure from your code sample, what `context` is, so I can't say for sure if doing a retrieve on that will return your `parent4` object. You might need to have two loops, one for existing `cs_parent` records to create child records for them, and another loop to create child records for parent records in the `request.Requests` list that are not yet in the system... Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I realise I misread part of the question, but the following still applies to the **new** parent record you want to create. Add it to the `ExecuteTransactionRequest` Requests.

Add the children to the parent [Entity's RelatedEntities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.relatedentities.aspx) collection (pseudo-example):

```
// Create parent object
var invoice = new Entity("invoice");
// Create list of child objects
var invoiceDetailList = new List<Entity>() { new Entity("invoicedetail"), new Entity("invoicedetail") };
// Add child records to parent record's RelatedEntities
invoice.RelatedEntities.Add(new Relationship("invoice_invoicedetails"), new EntityCollection(invoiceDetailList));
// Add to ExecuteTransactionRequest.
transactionRequest.Requests.Add(new CreateRequest { Target = invoice });
```

This way you don't need to know the parent record's GUID up front.